# whats the alternative to user defined functions in excel online office.js javascript lib

Tags: office-js, office-2016, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to develop the office excel add-in, similar to one i had for office 2013. in that i was using user defined function created using "VBA" and could fetch the data in the cells.

The advantage i had was
1. if i close my excel file and open it again, i could refresh the function and it would fetch the latest data.

i want to achieve something similar to that,

let me know how to achieve that using office js apis, I know that user defined functions are not supported in excel online

Answer (score 1):

The community has requested that Microsoft consider implementing this via the Excel and Office Developer Platform UserVoice pages;

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6936956-add-user-defined-function-support-to-the-apps-for

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-online/suggestions/10243059-support-udf-user-defined-function-in-excel-online

One of these appears to be 'started', so hopefully we will see this feature in the Office Javascript API soon!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript custom functions in Excel are now available in Developer Preview for anyone to try: https://aka.ms/customfunctions

-Michael, PM for add-ins

Comment: can you also help with this question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100262/workbook-protection-stopped-working-with-excel-online?noredirect=1#comment81199836_47100262