# Workbook Protection stopped working with Excel Online

Tags: excel, office-js

Until a few weeks ago, the [workbook protection API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheetprotection.md#protectoptions-worksheetprotectionoptions) was working in Excel Online. Now it gives error as invalid parameter.

I'm setting `allowInsertColumns: false` and `allowFormatCells: false`.

My code looks like this:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3").format.protection.locked = false;

    sheet.protection.protect({
        allowInsertColumns: false,
        allowFormatCells: false
    });

    $('#mytestlabel1').text("Execution of protect api call is complete");

    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        $('#mytestlabel').text("Sync operation is complete");
    });

}).catch(function (error) {

    $('#mytestlabel').text(error.message);
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }

});
```

I get exception when `ctx.sync` is done

Does anybody know what has changed, and how to fix this?

Comment: Does setting these one at a time have any effect?

Comment: no, it still doesn't work, logged defect in github too https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1185

Comment: Just to clarify, it doesn't matter which permission you try to set?

Comment: i didnot understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The product team is aware of this issue and is working on a fix.

See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1185 for details.